# RockPaperScissors with multiple methods

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a rockpaperscissors game using multiple methods but I'm having some trouble. I've done everything up to the main method but I seem to be having a little bit of trouble creating an input validation loop.

Here is the code:

The method I believe is causing me grief is this one

```
  while (isValid(x) == false)
  {
     System.out.print("Invalid Input: Please try again\n");
     x = getUserChoice();
     isValid(x);
  }
```

Here is the full source:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
   public static String getComputerChoice()
   {
   Random r = new Random();
   String[] compInput = new String[3];
   compInput[0] = "Rock";
   compInput[1] = "Paper";
   compInput[2] = "Scissors";
   int random = r.nextInt(2) + 1;

   return compInput[random];
   }

   public static String getUserChoice()
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      String input;
      System.out.print("Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ");
      input = kb.nextLine();

      return input;
   }

   public static boolean isValid(String userChoice)
   {
      if (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock"))
         return false;
      else if (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
         return false;
      else if (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors"))
         return false;
      else
      return true;
   }

   public static void displayOutcome(String choice1, String choice2)
   {
      if (choice1.length() - 1 > choice2.length() -1)
      {
         if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Wins: paper beats rock.");
         else if (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Wins: scissors beat paper");
         else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")))
            System.out.print("\nComputer Wins: Rock Beats Scissors");
      }

      if (choice2.length() - 1 > choice1.length() -1)
      {
         if (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
            System.out.print("\nComputer Wins: paper beats rock.");
         else if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
            System.out.print("\nComputer Wins: scissors beat paper");
         else if (choice2.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")))
            System.out.print("\nPlayer Wins: Rock Beats Scissors");
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String x = getUserChoice();
      String y = getComputerChoice();

      while (isValid(x) == false)
      {
         System.out.print("Invalid Input: Please try again\n");
         x = getUserChoice();
         isValid(x);
      }

      displayOutcome(x, y);
   }
}
```

Comment: I just read the first line of code and already wanted to point out that instead of `while (isValid(x) == false)` you can just write `while (!isValid(x))`

Comment: Also, *"but I'm having some trouble"* doesn't help us much. Please explain how the program fails. What does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush when I initially posted this but the program works perfectly besides for the while loop. Even if I type the correct word in it will still output the Invalid Input, i think it has something to do with the isValid(x). When I debugged it seemed like it never went back into the isValid method. Sorry for not being very clear initially.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have not told us the observable results you're expecting, the observable results you're actually observing, and what your question is, I'll try my best.

Your code has many problems.

The last line of the `while` loop body is `isValid(x);`, which simply determines a value of `true` or `false`, then ignores it. You can delete that line with no effect on the program logic.

You assign `Random r = new Random();` every time you call `getComputerChoice`. That makes the result not random. Instead, initialize a `final` instance of `Random` outside the method, in your case as a static member.

In your logic `if (choice1.length() - 1 > choice2.length() -1)`, not only is the `-1` on both sides of the comparison superfluous, but it's not a good way to compare outcomes. The logic is not obvious, and if you were to change the strings in any way, let's say translate them into another language, the accident of string length will not be useful. Use direct logic, perhaps like this if the choices were `enum` constants:

```
public enum RpsChoices {
  ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS, ;

  public static Boolean beats(RpsChoices left, RpsChoices right) {
    if (left == null || right == null || left == right ) {
      return null;
    }
    switch (left) {
    case ROCK:
      return right == SCISSORS;
    case PAPER:
      return right == ROCK;
    case SCISSORS:
      return right == PAPER;
    }
  }
}
```

You would then have

```
public static void displayOutcome(RpsChoices player, RpsChoices computer) {
  Boolean outcome = RpsChoices.beats(player, computer);
  if (outcome == null) {
    System.out.println("Tie: Player threw " + player
        + ", computer threw " + computer);
  }
  else if (outcome) {
    System.out.println("Player wins: Player threw " + player
        + ", computer threw " + computer);
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Computer wins: Player threw " + player
        + ", computer threw " + computer);
  }
}
```

Then your `isValid` loop boils down to:

```
for (RpsChoices choice = RpsChoices.valueOf(getUserChoice().toUpperCase());
     choice != null;
     choice = RpsChoices.valueOf(getUserChoice().toUpperCase())) {
  displayOutcome(choice, getComputerChoice());
}
```

which is optimized by not having the `isValid` method at all.

This is far more clear to maintainers, easier to understand, less subject to bugs like misspellings, and performant (although performance is moot in something this small).